# How to create an transparent gif/png image with translucent color patch?

Tags: java, image-processing, transparent, gif, translucency

I want to create gif/png image file using java programatically. This gif/png image should be transparent and a certain patch of color of specified rectangular size and at specified location should be translucent. I have height and width of the image in pixels. I also have x,y coordinate placing that rectangular colored translucent patch and also have the height and width of that colored translucent patch.

Is it possible to create a gif/png image with above specification programatically in Java? 
How to create such gif/png image?

As I don't know image processing in java please guide me friends to achieve this task.

Comment: GIF supports transparency but not translucency.  For partial transparency, use a PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BufferedImage` with an alpha channel.  Get the `Graphics` object of the image.  Paint to it whatever you like.  Save it as a PNG using `ImageIO`.

For documentation, see the JavaDocs for each of those classes.  For a tutorial, I recommend the [2D Graphics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) Trail of the Java Tutorial.

As for demo. code, I am too busy to go trawling through my 'throwaway' codes for an example of creating a PNG with partial transparency.  Especially since if I posted it, you'd probably complain that the partially transparent part is a circle rather than a square.

Why not give it your best shot based on the leads I've already provided, and if you get stuck, post an [sscce](/questions/tagged/sscce) of your best effort to the thread as an edit to your question?

Comment: Thank You! Sir! for your guidance Please tell me any documentation or tutorial where I will get any reference and a demo code of image  processing. Thanks You!